# Client Object Model : "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: The request uses too many resources"

Tags: client-object-model, delete, exception-handling, resources, batch

When deleting 1000+ (link) items from a list in one batch using the COM, I encountered this exception :

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: The request uses too many resources
```

It seems that there is a limitation for the request size. [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163082%28v=office.15%29.aspx) has some details.
After some trial and error and help from that webpage above, I found out that the maximum number of deletions (in one batch) is 252.
However I did not find the maximum number of new ListItem additions in one batch, so I decided to limit this to 100 in my code.

Is there a way to determine this or is there any documentation on this topic ?

Answer (score 7):

I've found a post on msdn that explains the request limits on the bottom of the page.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163082.aspx

> SharePoint has a 2 MB limit for an operations request, and
>   a 50 MB limit for the size of a submitted binary object. The request
>   size is limited to protect the server from excessively long queues of
>   operations and from processing delays for large binary objects. For
>   example, if you use the CSOM to create a project, and then edit the
>   project to add 252 tasks with a minimum amount of information such as
>   a short name, the task GUID, and a duration of 1d, the total amount of
>   data in the DraftProject.Update request is less than 2 MB. But, if you
>   try to add 253 such tasks to an empty project, the 2 MB limit is
>   exceeded, and you get the following exception:
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: The request uses too many
>   resources

Comment: Can you please add an abstract from the link to make your answer more valuable :)

Comment: I added an abstract from the link :)

Comment: Thanks for the abstract. Even Microsoft docs tend to disappear over time.

Answer (score 4):

The limit of items to be accessed in one call by the Client Object Model is defined by the `SPWebApplication.ClientCallableSettings.MaxObjectPaths` property. This applies to Add, Delete and Update operations too.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplication.clientcallablesettings.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spclientcallablesettings.maxobjectpaths.aspx

It is set by default to 256 and you can change it if you have access to the WebApplication. Here is how to change it:
http://ojasmaru.blogspot.in/2013/03/error-in-sharepoint-2010-client-object.html